Tensorflow : TypeError: create_estimator_and_inputs() missing 1 required positional argument: 'hparams'
Hello everyone I am trying to train my object detection model using model_main.py from Tensorflow
But when I execute the command in the cmd : python model_main.py --alsologtostderr --model_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
it return the following lines: (it works well with train.py But i want to see the eval at the same time)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main.py", line 110, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\dell3\PycharmProjects\Rockartv3\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\dell3\PycharmProjects\Rockartv3\venv\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\dell3\PycharmProjects\Rockartv3\venv\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "model_main.py", line 72, in main
    FLAGS.sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples))
TypeError: create_estimator_and_inputs() missing 1 required positional argument: 'hparams'

Did anyone know how to solve this ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The error message you're encountering indicates that there's a missing argument (hparams) in the function create_estimator_and_inputs() within your model_main.py script. This typically happens when the script is expecting certain arguments to be passed to it but they are not provided correctly.Ensure that the version of TensorFlow you are using is compatible with the version of model_main.py you have. TensorFlow updates sometimes change the APIs and function signatures, leading to compatibility issues.

Verify that the pipeline_config_path argument (training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config in your case) is correct and points to a valid pipeline configuration file. This file should define the model architecture, training parameters, and evaluation settings.
